# Python - add a numpy array as column to a pandas dataframe with different length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with multiple columns. One of the columns is `Col1` which contains float values or NaNs:

```
df
+----+------+-----+
| No | Col1 | ... |
+----+------+-----+
| 12 |   10 | ... |
| 23 |  NaN | ... |
| 34 |    5 | ... |
| 45 |  NaN | ... |
| 54 |   22 | ... |
+----+------+-----+
```

I run a function over `Col1` excluding missing values (`NaN`) like this:

```
StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.loc[pd.notnull(df[Col1]), [Col1]])
```

Imagine the result is a numpy.ndarray like this:

```
+-----+
| Ref |
+-----+
|   2 |
|   5 |
|   1 |
+-----+
```

Notice that this array does not have same length than the original column `Col1`.

I need a solution to add the array `Ref` as a column to `df`. For each row where `Col1` is `NaN`, the new column `Ref` gets `NaN` too. 
Desired output would look like this:

```
+----+------+-----+-----+
| No | Col1 | ... | Ref |
+----+------+-----+-----+
| 12 |   10 | ... |   2 |
| 23 |  NaN | ... | NaN |
| 34 |    5 | ... |   5 |
| 45 |  NaN | ... | NaN |
| 54 |   22 | ... |   1 |
+----+------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can assign to new column filtered by same boolean mask:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

mask = df['Col1'].notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Ref'] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.loc[mask, ['Col1']])
print (df)
   No  Col1       Ref
0  12  10.0 -0.327089
1  23   NaN       NaN
2  34   5.0 -1.027992
3  45   NaN       NaN
4  54  22.0  1.355081
```

**Detail**:

```
print (StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.loc[mask, ['Col1']]))
[[-0.32708852]
 [-1.02799249]
 [ 1.35508101]]
```